# :checked css not working

Tags: html, css, less

I have a product listing little square thing, when I click it ( it's a label ) it should tick the box and it does but it should make the border green and hold it but it doesn't I have this:

```
.product {
width: 100%;
background: #fff;
border: 4px solid #fff;
border-radius: 4px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #ddd;
text-align:center;
padding-bottom: 15px;
cursor: pointer;

-webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
-moz-transition: all .3s ease;
-o-transition: all .3s ease;
-ms-transition: all .3s ease;
transition: all .3s ease;

a {
    color: #d6d6d6;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 10px;

    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;

    &:hover {
        background: #e2e1e1;
        color: #333;
        text-decoration: none
    }
}

img {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 15px auto;
    pointer-events: none;
}

span {
    display: block;

    &.brand {
        color: #cdcfd2;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
    }

    &.name {
        color: #232f3e;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 600;
    }
}

&:hover {
    border: 4px solid #d9dce1;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

}

and this works great it's .less my html looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
<label for="product_id" name="product_id" class="product">
    <a href="#" title="product">i</a>
    <div class="position">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="product_id" id="product_id">
    </div>
    <img src="assets/images/products/image.jpg">
    <span class="brand">Brand</span>
    <span class="name">Product</span>
</label>
```

How do I would I apply the suggestions in this [`checked:`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/) example?

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label { }
```

It looks pretty simple but when I add it it doesn't work all I want is the .product border to be green instead of grey when it's selected

I know I can use js but I don't want to css should do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`+` is an adjacent sibling selector, meaning it matches the element after it based on the selector. Simply add a `label` tag after your `<input type="checkbox">` tag.

```css
.product {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
.product a {
  color: #d6d6d6;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
.product a:hover {
  background: #e2e1e1;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.product img {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 15px auto;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.product span {
  display: block;
}
.product span.brand {
  color: #cdcfd2;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.product span.name {
  color: #232f3e;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.product:hover {
  border: 4px solid #d9dce1;
  box-shadow: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
<label for="product_id" name="product_id" class="product">
    <a href="#" title="product">i</a>
    <div class="position">
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="product_id" id="product_id">
      <label for="product_id">label</label>
    </div>
    <img src="assets/images/products/image.jpg">
    <span class="brand">Brand</span>
    <span class="name">Product</span>
</label>
```

Comment: I don't get it, I mean your code looks exactly like mine but when I run it, it doesn't work.

Comment: @BrodeySheppard when you run my code it doesn't work? Your code and mine isn't the same. You don't have a label as an adjacent sibling to the input checkbox and you don't have the `:checked + label` entry in your CSS. If you put my code somewhere and that isn't working, link me to it or update your post with it or something so I can see.

Comment: No when i run your code it works, within stackoverflow, if I add input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  color: red;
} to my css, it doesn't work.

Comment: @BrodeySheppard you need to have a `label` tag as the next tag after the `input` checkbox for that CSS to work. Like this - `<input type="checkbox"><label>label</label>`

Comment: Arrr, Direcly after so I cannot have it in the div like I had it must be the next item! thanks heaps.

Comment: @BrodeySheppard np!

Answer (score 3):

to work "+" tags need to go one by one

css:
`input[type=checkbox]:checked + label { }`

html:
`<input type="checkbox" id="id"><label for="id">...</label>`

```css
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="id">
<label for="id">Test</label>
```

Comment: so your saying all I need to do is move the html so the input is above the label? I tried it and didn't work.

Comment: Yeah it seems to work in everyones example, but it doesn't work on my real life product. I don't know.

Comment: @BrodeySheppard pls place in u question compiled css, i fixed it

Answer (score 2):

**For anyone struggling**

The input and the element that you're modifying need to be directly next to the each other, for the `:checked` rule to work.

```css
#hidden {
  display: none;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
:checked + #hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="my_checkbox" style="display:none;">
<!-- NEED TO BE NEXT TO EACH OTHER ^ -->
<div id="hidden"></div>

<label for="my_checkbox">Show/hide</label>
```